# Finding a word in a file using Shell in Terminal on macOS

Tags: regex, macos, shell

I have a text file with a line among others:

```
Submitting job with ID: 50fd2805-6fcc-4bc6-91a2-638528180ab6
```

(It's a full line, and it has other lines before and after.)

I need to find and extract to a variable the ID. I came up with a RexEx pattern:

```
[\da-f]{8}(-[\da-f]{4}){3}-[\da-f]{12}
```

The patterns should work, but it doesn't seem to work in Shell with anything I tried: grep, sed – whatever.

One of my attempts was this:

```bash
JOB_ID=$(grep '[\da-f]{8}(-[\da-f]{4}){3}-[\da-f]{12}' file)
```

To be clear, as a result I need `JOB_ID` to contain string "50fd2805-6fcc-4bc6-91a2-638528180ab6" (without quotes.)

I'm sorry for such a seemingly noob question, but I couldn't find anything on the internet: I've read dozens of similar questions on SO and SE, and googled several tutorials, and still couldn't figure out the answer.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: No, it doesn't. The pattern is OK, it works in other environments. But I can't put it into use in a Shell script. So, perhaps I need another Shell command, or parameters, or to use some special format in the pattern – I don't know and seek for guidance.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Does `grep '[0-9a-f]\{8\}\(-[0-9a-f]\{4\}\)\{3\}-[0-9a-f]\{12\}'` work better?

Comment: @Biffen I tried to escape braces, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk` to print the last field on a line starting `Submitting` like this:

```
JOB_ID=$(awk '/^Submitting/ {print $NF}' file)
```